# MySQL date to Javascript date

Tags: javascript, mysql, date

I get a date from MySQL in the following format:

```
Sat Dec 10 1988 19:40:16 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

I want to convert this to a Javascript date so that I can easily supply JSON timestamps for data readings (Probably in the format YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:ss). How can I do that?

Comment: which programming language are you using ? and what is the problem with current format ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm using Javascript, and I want to get it into a Javascript Date object.

Comment: You can't access db using plain javascript AFAIK. You should have some server side programming

Comment: I access MySQL using Javascript's MySQL library, but that is irrelevant. I want to store the String date format I posted into a Javascript Date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create a new Date with this string as the parameter for the constructor:

```
new Date('Sat Dec 10 1988 19:40:16 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)');
```

This works because it's a format compatible with RFC2822.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

This will give you exactly what you want.

```
var d = new Date('Sat Dec 10 1988 19:40:16 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)');


formated_date  = [d.getMonth()+1,d.getDate(),d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
                 [d.getHours(),d.getMinutes(),d.getSeconds()].join(':');
```